# Counting records in a week with matching fields but ignoring matches on the same day

Tags: sql

I have 4 columns in the table Shipping: CustomerID, CustomerName, Shipping Address and Invoice Date. Customer ID is the unique identifier in this table.

I have a 6 month date period, 02-13-2014 to 08-13-2014, that holds 60,000 records. Each record has those four columns and they are NON-nullable columns.  I need to split this 6 month period into 7 day week blocks of time spanning the whole 6 months, and then count the number of records that appear more than once with the same CustomerID and Shipping Address per the 7 day weeks.

My end goal is to find how many of our customers get deliverys more than once a week to the same shipping address. If there is any record that appears more than once with the same customer ID and shipping address, it will mean that it is a delivery.

The kicker is, I don't care if there are multiple records with the same customer ID and shipping address if they are on the same day. I still need to know a record is there for that day, but I don't care how many are there.

Comment: One thing you may wanna do is format your question a bit better.  Walls of text are hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines might get you started:

```
SELECT ShippingAddress, DATEPART(wk, InvoiceDate), COUNT(*) AS countForWeek
  FROM shipping
  GROUP BY ShippingAddress, DATEPART(wk, InvoiceDate)
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: how did you put that sql code in the comment. Did you copy and paste it from a sql editor?

Comment: @Amicheals Bracket strings with the back-tick character like `so and so` (ie this character: `) to format as code.